Alignment style of an edge's node label within a path
I want to use a line break within a label. For that, an alignment like align=center must be specified or otherwise \\ is ignored. However, I do not know how to apply that style if the label belongs to a node within an edge within a path. I tried different combinations, but align=center was never recognized.
It would be even better to apply the style to all labels within a scope.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[>={Stealth[black]},
              every node/.style={fill=white,circle},
              every edge/.style={draw=red,very thick}]
        \path [->] (0, 0) edge node {$1.0\\2.0$} (2, 2);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Split your label into two math expressions and break the line between the math expressions, not within:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[>={Stealth[black]},
              every node/.style={fill=white,circle},
              every edge/.style={draw=red,very thick}]
        \path [->] (0, 0) edge node[align=center] {$1.0$\\$2.0$} (2, 2);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


